# Which are the best apps and websites for insect identification?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

My kids keep asking me to identify some insects they found, and I am often caught off guard, as I have very little matter knowledge.

I have found the *Insect Orders* app quite useful, but still quite challenging.

Is there anything else, in terms of apps or websites, which is better for insect identification?

Comment: I think many reliable websites and apps of high quality will have a relatively narrow scope both geographically and taxonomically. The exception might be some keys to the level of orders and maybe some families. I therefore think this question is rather broad and opinion-based. Where do you live and what level of taxonomic determination are you after (species, families, orders etc; what taxonomic groups)?

Comment: @fileunderwater, though I 100% agree that targeting resources that focus on specific geographic locations is best, there are a number of general sites (such as bugguide and even this site) which can lead to identification of insects from a broad range of locations. If the OP is looking for more general resources, then I think this question is valid (i.e., not too broad) and should be reopened. IMO.

Comment: However, given my last comment, @Joe_74, you could provide a more specific location, and we could try to provide some resources that are more specific to your location.

Answer (score 1):

There are not many beginner-friendly apps that I am aware of. However, there are a few websites you can use.

[BugGuide](http://bugguide.net) has a relatively nice picture-based search system. You will also gradually learn to easily identify various characteristics of an insect, thus making your search easier.

[Insect identification](http://www.insectidentification.org) is more beginner-friendly and more suitable to your kids.

You can also ask either here, or perhaps in [the reddit community](https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthisbug) if you have trouble identifying a particular bug.

If they become interested I would recommend searching your local book store or library for a good field guide (depending on your location). Entomology can be a fun excuse to get out of your house and learn something in the process.